# Why won't this fill command work?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I am trying to use the fill command to save time on a city build but it won't work... The command looks like this: `/fill 45 3 -43 -45 3 -47` and of course the block. The block is black concrete and I'm wondering if it's not able to be used for the command.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java Edition, in PE/BE all concrete has the namespaced ID `concrete`. What differentiates the different colours is the [data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Concrete#Block_data). For example, black concrete is `concrete` with a data value of 15.

The data value is used after the block name in the command:

```
/fill 45 3 -43 -45 3 -47 concrete 15
```